# Restore deleted iTunes backup of iPhone

Tags: iphone, backup, restore

I mistakenly deleted the latest backup for my iPhone from within iTunes preferences. How can I recover it?

I looked into `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup` and it is not there anymore. Where can I find the deleted folder containing the last backup?

I have a MacBook Air running Mac OS X El Capitan and an iPhone 5C running iOS 9.3.5.

Answer (score 2):

Start by looking for it in Trash. If not, than a Time Machine backup. If not, try recovering it using a recovery software. The backup folder generally contain many files with cryptic names like `0d0c1bdbcfa1d8f0cde357e7a4ab3db7783e26ff` and it may not be easy to deduce the correct one out of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found in the Trash a -ipsw file but I cannot open it... I didn't empty my trash and I don't use TimeMachine or iCloud (shame on me...). I know the beginning of my file name but i don't know where to find it... Does iTunes has a special folder where the deleted stuff are in there ?

Comment: The ipsw, is just the iOS update - you can get a fresh one of those any time from Apple. Your backup is thousands of cryptically-named files, there will be nothing recognisable in there.

Comment: Ok thank you... I can't recover my deleted backup then...